# OpenXml - Unable to create and assign stylesheet to MS Excel

Tags: c#, excel-2007, openxml

I am trying to create an excel spreadsheet using OpenXml 2.0 and C#. I can able to create a plain excel without any format with data table values from database. But, when I try to create a new style to apply on some specific fields, the excel is created but unable to open and throws error message:

> Excel has stopped working.

Below is the code I use to create `StyleSheet`.

```
SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(filepath,SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);

// Add a WorkbookPart to the document.
WorkbookPart workbookpart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();
workbookpart.Workbook = new Workbook();
workbookpart.Workbook.Save();

// Add a WorksheetPart to the WorkbookPart.
WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookpart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();   
worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());
worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();           

WorkbookStylesPart stylePart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>();

Stylesheet styleSheet = new Stylesheet();
CellFormats cellFormats = new CellFormats() { Count = (UInt32Value)1U };
CellFormat cellFormat = new CellFormat(new Alignment { WrapText = true });
cellFormats.Append(cellFormat);
styleSheet.Append(cellFormats);

styleSheet.Save(stylePart);
//stylePart.Stylesheet = styleSheet;
//stylePart.Stylesheet.Save();

UInt32Value styleIndex = styleSheet.CellFormats.Count;
```

Can someone please help to fix this issue. If I comment the `StyleSheet` creation part, the excel is generated and accessing perfectly. Can some one check this and explain what is going wrong.